# Partioning the hard disk and free space

Tags: partitioning

As shown in the screen shot, I completely removed windows and installed Ubuntu in the whole disk.

1. How to free some space and  partition the disk without reinstalling again?
2. It's a 2 TB internal hard disk and it shows only 1.8 TB, how can I retrieve the remaining 200GB?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You've not actually lost any space.

What you're seeing is "Advertised Space" vs "Actual Space".

This is a very simplified explanation:

All data is stored in binary (called a *bit*), 8x bits = a *Byte*.  This is basic binary mathematics, or *Base 2*.

Hard drives are advertised with space based on *Base 10* mathematics (the kind we use every day for normal calculations).

Because humans don't think in Base 2 mathematics, manufacturers create advertising using the standard Base 10 mathematics, as we can all understand it clearly.

In conclusion, your drive is advertised as 2Tb, but in Base 2 mathematics, your drive actually holds 1,862.65Gb.

For the most part, it was a marketing decision.

Further Reading: http://www.ussscctv.com/harddrivesizecapacitiescalculator.aspx